# Is it possible to take a string and put it in the System.in?

Tags: java, string, input, io, port

I wanted to know if there was a way to take a `String` - let's say:

```
String str = "blabla";
```

and do:

```
System.in.setText(str);
```

I know this does not work - I wanted to know if there was a way to do this. And then send that same string. Just like if you would write in the console and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

It is a program with a server socket and I am trying to send a `String` over a port, so that the other application would know what to do with it.

**EDIT :**
 I found a way to redirect the inputstream to a Textfield when the user writes in the Textfield it sends it over the System.in.

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;

public class TextfieldInputStream extends InputStream implements DocumentListener {

    private JTextField tf;
    private String str = null;
    private int pos = 0;

    public TextfieldInputStream(JTextField jtf) {
        tf = jtf;
    }

    @Override
    public int read() {
        //test if the available input has reached its end
        //and the EOS should be returned 
        if(str != null && pos == str.length()){
            str = null;
            //this is supposed to return -1 on "end of stream"
            //but I'm having a hard time locating the constant
            return java.io.StreamTokenizer.TT_EOF;
        }
        //no input available, block until more is available because that's
        //the behavior specified in the Javadocs
        while (str == null || pos >= str.length()) {
            try {
                //according to the docs read() should block until new input is available
                synchronized (this) {
                    this.wait();
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        //read an additional character, return it and increment the index
        return str.charAt(pos++);
    }

    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e){
        str = tf.getText() + "\n";
        pos = 0;
        synchronized (this) {
            //maybe this should only notify() as multiple threads may
            //be waiting for input and they would now race for input
            this.notifyAll();
        }
    }

    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e){
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

Comment: well its a program with a server socket and i was trying to send a String over a port. so that the other application would know what to do with it

Comment: i'm confused, if you are trying to send a string over a port, shouldn't you be using a Socket, not System.in?

Comment: @jtahlborn  Great comment.  I was 'coding to (the original) spec.', but mention of ports makes it perhaps quite a different question & approach.

Comment: Well the first application initialise a Server socket and then the second one is a client wich connects to it. this part works fine. i just cant seem to send progammaticly any command(String) i need to use the console this i were this question came up. If you want me to i can show u the server code and client code

Comment: the more code you show, the better.  you keep saying "console" and you also talk about sockets (2 very different, unrelated things).  it's very confusing how it all fits together.

Comment: now the question became a bit out of the context haha!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
package test.t100.t007;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SystemIn {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "blabla";
        ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(str.getBytes());
        System.setIn(bais);
        // We might use the ByteArrayInputStream here, but going with System.in..
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = scanner.next();
        System.out.println(input);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use a `PipedInputStream/PipedOutputStream` pair. Then you can set the `PipedInputStream` as `System.in` using `System.setIn()` method. Finally you can write to your `PipedOutputStream` and have the result available in System.in.